# Ranked Set Sampling

Tags: self-study, sampling, ranks

In ranked set sampling, we select $n$ random sets, each of size $n$. Then we choose the largest unit from the 1st set, 2nd largest from the 2nd set, and thus $n$th largest from the $n$th set. This sampling procedure was first introduced by McIntyre (1952). The reference is [A method for unbiased selective sampling, using ranked sets. Australian Journal of Agricultural Research, 3(4), 385-390.](http://dlx.booksc.org/11200000/libgen.scimag11249000-11249999.zip/browse/10.1198/000313005x54180.pdf) In this paper, I am not understanding what did the author mean by

> *"distribution of samples of the same rank from sets of five random samples"*

in figure 1. Especially, does `same rank` mean the third distribution is a distribution of only third largest unit? If so, what is the interpretation of this bell shaped curve?